# Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, grpc

After few transaction while using Dialogflow APIs, `DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded` error is coming and after that I always need to restart the service, then again it starts working for a while. Not getting any relevant answers even after trying lots of blogs.

Using node package: dialogflow
and dialogflow standard edition (Free Version)

Tried with various agent of Dialogflow, but not getting the response.

> Error: 4 DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline Exceeded
>        at Object.exports.createStatusError (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
>        at Object.onReceiveStatus (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1188:28)
>        at InterceptingListener._callNext (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:564:42)
>        at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:614:8)
>        at callback (/srv/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:841:24)
>      code: 4,
>      metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} },
>      details: 'Deadline Exceeded' }

While using `dialogflow` node package, and here using

```
const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient();
```

to detect intent not getting the result as detected intent after hitting query for a phrase.

Answer (score 1):

The DEADLINE_EXCEEDED error is triggered when the webhook call exceeds the maximum wait time.

As stated on [DialogFlow fulfillment documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-how):

> The response must occur within 10 seconds for Actions on Google
>   applications or 5 seconds for all other applications, otherwise the
>   request will time out.

If you want, on dialogflow, you can set a pre-defined message that is sent when the fulfillment request exceeds the available time.

Comment: Where can you set the message for deadline_exceeded?