# Why does GitLab merge request returns "500 Internal Server Error"?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ee

My user wants to merge a request on our hosted GitLab EE 11.5.2 website.
But the website returns **500 Internal Server Error** as follows:

[image]

The related log is as follows:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 56565ms (ActiveRecord: 746.1ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (4:Deadline Exceeded):
  42:             %li.diffs-tab
  44:                 Changes
  45:                 %span.badge.badge-pill= @merge_request.diff_size
  46:
  47:     #diff-notes-app.tab-content
  48:       #new.commits.tab-pane.active
lib/gitlab/gitaly_client/diff_stitcher.rb:13:in `each'
lib/gitlab/gitaly_client/diff_stitcher.rb:13:in `each'
lib/gitlab/git/diff_collection.rb:107:in `each_gitaly_patch'
lib/gitlab/git/diff_collection.rb:47:in `each'
lib/gitlab/git/diff_collection.rb:83:in `each_with_index'
lib/gitlab/git/diff_collection.rb:83:in `decorate!'
lib/gitlab/diff/file_collection/base.rb:32:in `diff_files'
lib/gitlab/diff/file_collection/base.rb:9:in `real_size'
app/models/merge_request.rb:411:in `diff_size'
app/views/projects/merge_requests/creations/_new_submit.html.haml:45:in `block in _app_views_projects_merge_requests_creations__new_submit_html_haml__4084413277917201848_70167460469980'
app/views/projects/merge_requests/creations/_new_submit.html.haml:43:in `_app_views_projects_merge_requests_creations__new_submit_html_haml__4084413277917201848_70167460469980'
app/views/projects/merge_requests/creations/new.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_projects_merge_requests_creations_new_html_haml__4204914316377908944_70167458972060'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:116:in `render'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:55:in `with_locale'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:61:in `with_user_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:427:in `set_locale'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:101:in `call'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
ee/lib/gitlab/jira/middleware.rb:15:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:17:in `call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:11:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:22:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:15:in `block in call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/transaction.rb:53:in `run'
lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:15:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:40:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:16:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'
lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:20:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:10:in
```

Could you please tell me how to troubleshoot this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: this may be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052839/error-4-deadline-exceeded-deadline-exceeded

Comment: Hi @shikida, thanks for your suggestion, I'll keep finding out the solution for this issue by the keyword "ActionView::Template::Error (4:Deadline Exceeded):" though there seems no answer for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eventually, we found the solution!

Though the merge request can be achieved by git command, it's not recommended by our security policy.

And the solution is that the merge request should be operated via "**Merge Requests**" instead of "**Repository > Branches**".

**The successful way:**
[image]

**The failed way:**
[image]